# HKStatisticsCollectionQuery resultsHandler and NSOperation

Tags: ios, nsoperation, healthkit

In my project I am creating HKStatisticsCollectionQueries for a series of HKQuantityTypes. The resultsHandler then adds this data to an date-ordered array of objects. I want to do another operation only when the entire series of HKStatisticsCollectionQueries have been processed and the results appended to my array.

I have tried to do this by putting the task inside of a subclass of  NSOperation, but the dependent block is fired before any of the samples are added to the array. According to the HKStatisticsCollectionQuery documentation "This method runs the query on an anonymous background queue. When the query is complete, it executes the results handler on the same background queue"

*Is there a way to use HKStatisticsCollectionQuery's initialResultsHandler and statisticsUpdateHandler with NSOperation?*

when I run this I get the following output:

cycleOperation start
cycleOperation CompletionBlock
dependentOperation start
dependentOperation CompletionBlock
SumStatistics addSamplesToArray: cycle:  96 samples added
SumStatistics main complete: 96 samples added

```
func getCycleKm(){
    let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling)
    let hkUnit = HKUnit.meterUnitWithMetricPrefix(.Kilo)
    println("cycleOperation start")

    let cycleOperation = SumStatistics(quantityType: sampleType, startDate: startingDate, heathDataArray: self.healthDataArray)
    cycleOperation.completionBlock = {println("cycleOperation CompletionBlock ")}
    let dependentOperation = NSBlockOperation{()->Void in println("dependentOperation start")}
    dependentOperation.completionBlock = {println("dependentOperation CompletionBlock")}
    dependentOperation.addDependency(cycleOperation)

    self.operationQueue.addOperation(cycleOperation)
    self.operationQueue.addOperation(dependentOperation)
}


class SumStatistics:NSOperation{

let healthKitStore:HKHealthStore = HKHealthStore()

private let quantityType:HKQuantityType
private let startDate:NSDate
private let endDate: NSDate
private let statsOption: HKStatisticsOptions

var healthDataArray:[HealthData]

required init(quantityType:HKQuantityType, startDate:NSDate, heathDataArray:[HealthData]){
    self.quantityType = quantityType
    self.startDate = startDate
    let startOfToday = NSDate().getStartOfDate()
    self.endDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: startOfToday, options: nil)!
    self.statsOption = HKStatisticsOptions.CumulativeSum
    self.healthDataArray = heathDataArray
    super.init()
}


override func main() {
    getSumStatistics { (hkSamples, statsError) -> Void in
        self.addSamplesToArray(hkSamples)
        println("SumStatistics main complete: \(hkSamples.count) samples added")
    }
}

func addSamplesToArray(newSamples:[HKQuantitySample]){
    var samples = newSamples
    samples.sort({$0.startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow > $1.startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow})
    if samples.count == 0{
        println("SumStatistics addSamplesToArray: no samples!")
        return
    }
    var ctr = 0
    var typeString = ""
    for healthDataDate in self.healthDataArray{

        while healthDataDate.date.isSameDate(samples[ctr].startDate) && ctr < samples.count - 1{
            switch samples[ctr].quantityType.identifier {
            case HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass:
                healthDataDate.weight = samples[ctr].quantity
                typeString = "weight"
            case HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed:
                healthDataDate.dietCalories = samples[ctr].quantity
                typeString = "diet"
            case HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned:
                healthDataDate.activeCalories = samples[ctr].quantity
                typeString = "active"
            case HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBasalEnergyBurned:
                healthDataDate.basalCalories = samples[ctr].quantity
                typeString = "basal"
            case HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount:
                healthDataDate.steps = samples[ctr].quantity
                typeString = "steps"
            case HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling:
                healthDataDate.cycleKM = samples[ctr].quantity
                typeString = "cycle"
            case HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning:
                healthDataDate.runWalkKM = samples[ctr].quantity
                typeString = "runWalk"
            default:
                println("SumStatistics addSamplesToArray type not found -> \(samples[ctr].quantityType)")
            }
            if ctr < samples.count - 1{
                ctr += 1
            }else{
                break
            }
        }
    }
    println("SumStatistics addSamplesToArray: \(typeString):  \(newSamples.count) samples added")
}




func getSumStatistics(completionHandler:([HKQuantitySample], NSError!)->Void){
    let dayStart = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(startDate)
    let addDay = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: endDate, options:nil)
    let dayEnd = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(addDay!)  //add one day
    let interval = NSDateComponents()
    interval.day = 1

    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate, endDate: endDate, options: HKQueryOptions.None)
    let newQuery = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantityType,
        quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
        options: statsOption,
        anchorDate: dayStart,
        intervalComponents: interval)

    newQuery.initialResultsHandler = {
        query, statisticsCollection, error in
        var resultsArray = [HKQuantitySample]()
        if error != nil {
            println("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
        }else{
            statisticsCollection.enumerateStatisticsFromDate(self.startDate, toDate: self.endDate, withBlock: { (statistics, stop) -> Void in
                if let statisticsQuantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                    let startD =    NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(statistics.startDate)
                    let endD = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: startD, options: nil)

                    let qSample = HKQuantitySample(type: self.quantityType, quantity: statisticsQuantity, startDate: startD, endDate: endD)
                    resultsArray.append(qSample)
                }
            })
        }
        completionHandler(resultsArray,error)
    }

    newQuery.statisticsUpdateHandler = {
        query, statistics, statisticsCollection, error in
        println("*** updateHandler fired")
        var resultsArray = [HKQuantitySample]()
        if error != nil {
            println("*** An error occurred while calculating the statistics: \(error.localizedDescription) ***")
        }else{
            statisticsCollection.enumerateStatisticsFromDate(self.startDate, toDate: self.endDate, withBlock: { (statistics, stop) -> Void in
                if let statisticsQuantity = statistics.sumQuantity() {
                    let startD =    NSCalendar.currentCalendar().startOfDayForDate(statistics.startDate)
                    let endD = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.CalendarUnitDay, value: 1, toDate: startD, options: nil)

                    let qSample = HKQuantitySample(type: self.quantityType, quantity: statisticsQuantity, startDate: startD, endDate: endD)
                    resultsArray.append(qSample)
                }
            })
        }
        completionHandler(resultsArray,error)
    }
    self.healthKitStore.executeQuery(newQuery)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The short answer was RTFM! (more carefully). I am leaving my original question and code as is, and adding the solution here.

Thanks to this post for helping me figure this out: http://szulctomasz.com/ios-second-try-to-nsoperation-and-long-running-tasks/ And of course, as I found, there is no substitute for a careful reading of the Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/

The problem was that I was not subclassing NSOperation properly for running **concurrent** operations. One must add the concurrent operations to start() rather than main() and then use KVO to update the finished and executing properties, which are what signals that an operation is complete.

I needed to modify the class above to include:

```
private var _executing = false
private var _finished = false

override var executing:Bool{return _executing}
override var finished:Bool{return _finished}
override func cancel() {
super.cancel()
finish()
}

override func start() {
if cancelled{
    finish()
    return
}
willChangeValueForKey("isExecuting")
_executing = true
didChangeValueForKey("isExecuting")

getSumStatistics { (hkSamples, statsError) -> Void in
    println("LoadStatistics getStatistics completion: \(hkSamples.count) samples")
    self.addSamplesToArray(hkSamples, completionHandler: { (success) -> Void in
       println("LoadStatistics addSamplesToArray completion")
       self.finish()

    })
    self.completion(true)
}
main()

}

func finish(){
willChangeValueForKey("isExecuting")
willChangeValueForKey("isFinished")
_executing = false
_finished = true
didChangeValueForKey("isExecuting")
didChangeValueForKey("isFinished")

}


override func main() {
if cancelled == true && _finished != false{
    finish()
    return
}
 }
```

Now I get!

cycleOperation start
LoadStatistics getStatistics completion: 97 samples
LoadStatistics addSamplesToArray completion
cycleOperation CompletionBlock
dependentOperation start
dependentOperation CompletionBlock